# Something Like Win App DataGridView in ASP.NET MVC3 With Update All Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a simple model in ASP.NET MVC3 and in Index View in front of each row 3 links appear (Edit, Details, Delete) With Edit Link the page navigate to edit view and you can edit that specific row, So I am interesting in edit all rows together like something in Win app by DataGridView, for example the table in Index view be Editable and an Update All button, Save edits for all rows, Does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit index view, like the following:

1- Replace `@Html.DisplayFor` with`@Html.EditorFor` for that columns you want to edit,

2- Add `@using (Html.BeginForm()){}` to included all of `<table>` tag,

3- Add a submit like this: `<input type="submit" value="Updata All" />` inside of `BeginForm()` block

4- Add a new `[HttpPost]` for Index action in your controller and handle edits you can use something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string[] Descriptions = collection.GetValues("item.Description");

       for (int i = 1; i <= Descriptions.Length; i++)
        {
            MyModel element = db.MyModels.Find(i);
            element.Description = Descriptions[i - 1];
            db.Entry(element).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(db.MyModels.ToList());
    }
```